# Unable to access child properties of SKNode

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode, sknode

I've got a for loop that sorts through children of a **SKNode**, and for some reason I can only access the child's properties of a **SKNode** and not **SKSpriteNode** properties such as size after **casting** it.

```
for tile in map.children where tile is SKSpriteNode {
    let tileBody = CGRect(origin: tile.position, size: tile.size)
}
```

Its saying that the tile which is **casted** as a **SKSpriteNode**, is a **SKNode**. Its still acting like a **SKNode** when it should be a **SKSpriteNode**. Any fix to this?

**EDIT**

I just force casted it with

```
let tile = tile as! SKSpriteNode
```

and that worked. I haven't had a problem yet, if you think is a improper way of casting it, I'd love to hear it.

Comment: You should supply an answer to your own question and not edit the question.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/

I'm going to assume "map" is an SKNode (or a sub of it). The documentation makes it clear that the children property is a read-only Array of SKNode. Your "where - is" only checks that an SKNode is an SKSpriteNode, it doesn't cast anything.

Once the condition passes (because the currently iterated SKNode can downcast to an SKSpriteNode) it's up to you to actually downcast it. That's what you're doing now and why it works. You can force downcast like you're doing now safely because you're checking whether it's an SKSpriteNode beforehand.

EDIT: Here's some documentation on the "is" operator you're using which is only an operator that returns true or false, it does not cast that SKNode to an SKSpriteNode and make that available in the inner scope.

"Use the type check operator (is) to check whether an instance is of a certain subclass type. The type check operator returns true if the instance is of that subclass type and false if it is not."

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html